# How to remember exclusion pattern in Find/Replace

Tags: sublimetext3

I remember in ST2, the find/replace always remembered my exclusion patterns across sessions. But in ST3, it doesn't.  How to make it happen?

I know about the "folder exclude patterns" settings, but I think that's only for the sidebar? and I dont want anything excluded there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you're referring to here is the `Where` field in the `Find in Files` panel, which allows you to specifically exclude certain files and folders from consideration while performing a search across multiple files.

It's a fairly recent innovation in ST3 to not maintain the history for these panels except within projects, and aside of that there is no way to maintain this information.

In particular (referencing the http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev):

- Build 3135, June 12 2017: `New Windows start with an empty find history`
- Build 3136, June 13 2017: `Dragging a tab into a new window preserves the find history`
- Build 3141, July 7, 2017: `Find settings, but not history, are now inherited by new windows`

If you are using saved Sublime projects, each such project will automatically have it's own workspace file saved, and the history is saved in there.

In that case switching to that project will still have the history (including `Where:`), as will creating a new window by first making a tab in that project and then dragging it out to a new window.

However outside of this, newly created windows always have a blank history.

Comment: Thanks OdatNurd! That helped me tremendously. I never used projects in sublime and simply opened each session at the root when I needed to work on the code. Couldn't find the doc about this for the life of me...